# bluezero remote api v-rep with python

Tags: python, api, anaconda, ros

I have some issues when I am trying to connect python to v-rep using Blue Zero based remote API. The community of v-rep didn't have enough details and I have followed their information such as:
copy and paste the py files from v-rep directory to folder project and also b0.dll file, also I have install msgpack using pip install but it didn't show it in the folder project. when I am trying to import the API as follow in spyder editor from Anaconda:

```
import b0RemoteApi
```

it shows me the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-42c3b157e1d8>", line 1, in <module>
    import b0RemoteApi

  File "C:path to folder project\b0RemoteApi.py", line 6, in <module>
    import b0

  File "C:path to folder project\b0.py", line 18, in <module>
    libb0 = ct.CDLL(libb0_fullpath)

  File "C:some pathes\Anaconda1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I am using windows 10 and I have worked on many suggestions but I didn't find out the solution. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, you need to add all the dependencies(.dll files) for BlueZero. 
They are already present inside the installation folder at different places.
The following dependencies you need to add:

1. boost (boost_date_time, boost_filesystem, boost_program_options,  boost_regex, boost_serialization, boost_thread)
2. libzmq
3. lz4
4. zlib